# How to add headers to OkHttp request interceptor?

Tags: java, android, http-headers, retrofit, okhttp

I have this interceptor that i add to my OkHttp client:

```
public class RequestTokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
  Request request = chain.request();
  // Here where we'll try to refresh token.
  // with an retrofit call
  // After we succeed we'll proceed our request
  Response response = chain.proceed(request);
  return response;
}
}
```

How can i add headers to request in my interceptor?

I tried this but i am making mistake and i lose my request when creating new request:

```
    public class RequestTokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request newRequest;

        try {
            Log.d("addHeader", "Before");
            String token = TokenProvider.getInstance(mContext).getToken();
            newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader(HeadersContract.HEADER_AUTHONRIZATION, O_AUTH_AUTHENTICATION + token)
                    .addHeader(HeadersContract.HEADER_CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_ID)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("addHeader", "Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }

        Log.d("addHeader", "after");
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Note that, i know i can add header when creating request like this:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://api.github.com/repos/square/okhttp/issues")
    .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json; q=0.5")
    .addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json")
    .build();
```

But it doesn't fit my needs. I need it in interceptor.

Comment: Your interceptor looks right. What's not working with it?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Finally, I added the headers this way:

```
@Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request newRequest;

        newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader(HeadersContract.HEADER_AUTHONRIZATION, O_AUTH_AUTHENTICATION)
                .addHeader(HeadersContract.HEADER_X_CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_ID)
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
```

Comment: for some reason this does not add the headers to my request?! I am using okHttp.Builder and networkInterceptors().add(interceptor) with the same code like in this answer, but the headers are not added.

Comment: how to add a header for youtube request?  Is it a packageName and your API key and then pass through `.addheader(params1, params2);`

Comment: @RoCk You can have separate RestClients which have different header configuration.

Answer (score 34):

you can do it this way

```
private String GET(String url, Map<String, String> header) throws IOException {
        Headers headerbuild = Headers.of(header);
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).headers(headerbuild).
                        build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

Comment: This is not an interceptor.

Answer (score 29):

here is a useful [gist](https://gist.github.com/lfmingo/768a29eafc4a9d25d75ef31e2be506f7) from [lfmingo](https://github.com/lfmingo)

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request request = original.newBuilder()
            .header("User-Agent", "Your-App-Name")
            .header("Accept", "application/vnd.yourapi.v1.full+json")
            .method(original.method(), original.body())
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}

OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 14):

Faced similar issue with other samples, this Kotlin class worked for me

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response

class CustomInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain) : Response {               
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .header("x-custom-header", "my-value")
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Retrofit library then you can directly pass header to api request using `@Header` annotation without use of Interceptor. Here is example that shows how to add header to Retrofit api request.

```
@POST(apiURL)
void methodName(
        @Header(HeadersContract.HEADER_AUTHONRIZATION) String token,
        @Header(HeadersContract.HEADER_CLIENT_ID) String token,
        @Body TypedInput body,
        Callback<String> callback);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know that, but i have a method to obtain the token named: getToken() that has wait on thread. so if i call that in OkHttp interceptor, it will run in retrofit thread and i do not need to worry about thread issues.

Answer (score 7):

There is yet an another way to add interceptors in your OkHttp3 (latest version as of now) , that is you add the interceptors to your Okhttp builder

```
okhttpBuilder.networkInterceptors().add(chain -> {
 //todo add headers etc to your AuthorisedRequest

  return chain.proceed(yourAuthorisedRequest);
});
```

and finally build your okHttpClient from this builder

```
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin version:

```kotlin
fun okHttpClientFactory(): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            chain.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader(HEADER_AUTHONRIZATION, O_AUTH_AUTHENTICATION)
                .build()
                .let(chain::proceed)
        }
        .build()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
class JSONHeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain) : Response {
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

```
fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(JSONHeaderInterceptor())
    return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.example.network.interceptors;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class RequestHeadersNetworkInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final Map<String, String> headers;

    public RequestHeadersNetworkInterceptor(@NonNull Map<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
            if (header.getKey() == null || header.getKey().trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (header.getValue() == null || header.getValue().trim().isEmpty()) {
                builder.removeHeader(header.getKey());
            } else {
                builder.header(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            }
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }

}
```

Example of usage:

```
httpClientBuilder.networkInterceptors().add(new RequestHeadersNetworkInterceptor(new HashMap<String, String>()
{
    {
        put("User-Agent", getUserAgent());
        put("Accept", "application/json");
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().header("authorization", token).url(url).build();
        MyWebSocketListener wsListener = new MyWebSocketListener(LudoRoomActivity.this);
        client.newWebSocket(request, wsListener);
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those to whom okhttp3 interceptor still does not work. **Consequence of adding interceptors is make sense!** Kotlin example

My interceptor:

```
class MyOkHttpInterceptor : Interceptor, Logging {
    
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val mdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()
        var request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .header(CommonConstants.WS_USER_AGENT, CommonConstants.WS_USER_AGENT_SEARCH)
                .header(CommonConstants.WS_HEADER_TRACED_ID, mdc[CommonConstants.WS_HEADER_TRACED_ID]!!)
                .header(CommonConstants.WS_HEADER_ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .method(chain.request().method, chain.request().body)
                .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)

    }
}
```

My logging interceptor:

```
val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
```

1. I am adding header interceptor
2. I am adding logging interceptor
3. **Do not use network interceptors!!!**

> 

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(httpConnectTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(httpConnectTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(readTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(MyOkHttpInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()
```