# OkHttp async interceptor or authenticator

Tags: okhttp

Is there any way to do interception or authentication of request async? For example in flow like this: get password from user, use it to obtain token an then retry the call that was intercepted?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196424/how-to-add-headers-to-okhttp-request-interceptor).

I use `wait()`and `notify()` in the getToken method in my code, but because i use OkHttp in Retrofit library, it is creating a new thread and makes it possible to have async operations here.

```
    public synchronized void getToken() throws InterruptedException {
    if (!isRefreshing()) {
        //This is very important to call notify() on the same object that we call wait();
        final TokenProvider myInstance = this;
        setRefreshing(true);
        Log.d("refreshToken", "Refreshing token..." );

       //Make async call
       getRestClient().getAccountService().getRefreshedToken(mLoginData.getRefreshToken())
                .subscribe(new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        synchronized (myInstance) {
                            setRefreshing(false);
                            Log.d("refreshToken", "notifyAll onComplete.");
                            myInstance.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        synchronized (myInstance) {
                            setRefreshing(false);
                            myInstance.notifyAll();
                            Log.d("refreshToken", "onError .");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
                        synchronized (myInstance) {
                            mLoginData = loginResponse;
                            Log.d("refreshToken", "notifyAll onNext .");
                            myInstance.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

        Log.d("refreshToken", "before wait ." + android.os.Process.getThreadPriority(android.os.Process.myTid()) + this.toString());
        this.wait();
        Log.d("refreshToken", "after wait ." + android.os.Process.getThreadPriority(android.os.Process.myTid()) + this.toString());
}
```

You can try if this works for you.