# How to intercept a request in OkHttp?

Tags: android, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

I'm trying to intercept a request in OkHttp and change the response on live.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.connectTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .writeTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .readTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
builder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());

return builder.build();
```

I have a request that ends with "/assets/v3". Is there any option to intercept this request and return a Json file stored in Raw Folder instead of the original response?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add headers to OkHttp request interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196424/how-to-add-headers-to-okhttp-request-interceptor)